# RegularExpressionValidator shows an exception that following field cannot be empty

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation

I have a textbox txtemailid which has two validator `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEMailId" CssClass="Text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtEMailId"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="*"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ForeColor="Red"
    ControlToValidate="txtEMailId"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REVtxtEMailId"
    runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"
    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

it shows following error

```
The ControlToValidate property of 'REVtxtEMailId' cannot be blank.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not have specified which control should be validated .Try this

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REVtxtEMailId"
    runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Format"
    ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtEMailId"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks Guys. i was missing this property.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided ControlTo Validate Property in Regular Expression Validator.Add this property in REVtxtEMailId